# Изменение значений в кортеже

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuple

У меня есть кортеж ("1", "2", "3"). Как можно преобразовать строковые значения в нём на значения типа int, что бы было так (1, 2, 3).

Необходимо перегнать значения из кортежа в список, чтобы они в списке были int и потом обернуть этот список в tuple вот так: tuple([1,2,3]).

Comment: Именно **изменить** значения в кортеже у Вас не получится, он неизменяемый. А вот преобразовать в список (как Вы сами предлагаете) возможно. Хотя лучше не в список, а сразу в новый кортеж

Comment: `tuple([1,2,3])` - так нельзя сделать, это выражение сразу превратиться в просто кортеж `(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно преобразовать каждую строку в число. Так как все строки находятся в коллекции, Вы можете проитерировать их с помощью цикла или функции [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

***Пример:***

```py
s = ("1", "2", "3")

n = tuple(map(int, s))
print(n)
```

***stdout:***

```py
(1, 2, 3)
```